# Liquibase changelog parameters not being picked up

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I'm upgrading a huge Spring Boot 1.x -based project to Spring Boot 2.2. The old version used Liquibase 3.5, and the current upgrade branch is using Liquibase 3.8.

The main changelog file has the following structure:

```
...
<include file="initialize-liquibase-properties.xml" />
<include file="001-first-changeset.yml" />
...
```

I.e. the first included changelog is a file containing global `property` settings used in all other changelog files.

This worked fine and dandy in the old code branch, but now, in the upgrade branch things broke: *properties seem not to be picked up*.

First I banged my head against the wall with the exception I was getting on application startup: Java's `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I was like "what the ...?!?" Then I started debugging, and found out, that the legacy XML-changelog was causing the exception. Finally I figured out that it was the usage of `${long_text_type}` that was causing the problem. `long_text_type` is defined in the aforementioned `initialise-liquibase-properties.xml` file as such:

```
<property name="long_text_type" dbms="postgresql, mysql" value="ntext" />
<property name="long_text_type" dbms="h2" value="nvarchar(100000)" />
```

Has Liquibase's property-reading system changed between 3.5 and 3.8?

As a workaround I'm using the approach defined here: https://reflectoring.io/database-migration-spring-boot-liquibase/ : my `application.yml` now contains, as an example:

```
---
spring:
  profiles: test
  liquibase:
    parameters:
      long_text_type: nvarchar(1000000)
---
spring:
  profiles: native
  liquibase:
    parameters:
      long_text_type: ntext
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it: the legacy code property definitions' dbms mentioned only *mysql* and that worked well with our **mariadb** when using Liquibase 3.5. Now, that I added mariadb to property definitions' dbms-list, things started to work again.